# What could be causing my texture in ash Vulkan to render lighter?

Tags: textures, vulkan, rust

I have just completed the Vulkan tutorial using rust and the ash crate. I've been following along with [this repository](https://github.com/unknownue/vulkan-tutorial-rust/blob/master/src/tutorials/29_multisampling.rs). I am unable to determine what is causing my textures to render lighter.  If anyone can enlighten me as to any probable causes for this that would help a great deal.

My shaders are very basic. They are the exact same as what's in the tutorial, so I've ruled them out. I originally thought my problem had to do with multisampling but I've just completed that part of the course with no improvements to the color of my textures.
[image: my render]

The texture I'm rendering from is directly taken from the [vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Loading_models) website. It looks as follows~[image]

As you can see my render is clearly lighter. You'll see I am using the "image.rs" crate to get raw byte data to create the texture.

```
pub fn create_texture_image(
    device: &ash::Device,
    command_pool: vk::CommandPool,
    submit_queue: vk::Queue,
    device_memory_properties: &vk::PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties,
    image_path: &std::path::Path
) -> (vk::Image, vk::DeviceMemory, u32) {

    //Get image data
    let mut image_object = image::open(image_path).unwrap();
    image_object = image_object.flipv(); // flip vertically

    // destructuring image data
    let (image_width, image_height) = (image_object.width(), image_object.height());
    let image_size =
        (std::mem::size_of::<u8>() as u32 * image_width * image_height * 4) as vk::DeviceSize;

    let mip_levels = ((std::cmp::max(image_width, image_height) as f32)
        .log2()
        .floor() as u32) 
        + 1;
    
    let image_data;
    image_data = match &image_object {
        image::DynamicImage::ImageLuma8(_) |
        image::DynamicImage::ImageBgr8(_) |
        image::DynamicImage::ImageRgb8(_) => image_object.to_rgba8().into_raw(),
        image::DynamicImage::ImageLumaA8(_) |
        image::DynamicImage::ImageBgra8(_) |
        image::DynamicImage::ImageRgba8(_) => image_object.to_rgba8().into_raw(),
        _ => { panic!("Image is not one of the 8 bit formats")}
    };

    if image_size <= 0 {
        panic!("Failed to load texture image");
    }

    let (staging_buffer, staging_buffer_memory) = buffer::create_buffer(
        &device,
        image_size,
        vk::BufferUsageFlags::TRANSFER_SRC,
        vk::MemoryPropertyFlags::HOST_VISIBLE | 
        vk::MemoryPropertyFlags::HOST_COHERENT,
        device_memory_properties,
    );

    unsafe {
        let data_ptr = device
            .map_memory(
                staging_buffer_memory,
                0,
                image_size,
                vk::MemoryMapFlags::empty(),
            ).expect("Failed to Map Memory") as *mut u8;

        data_ptr.copy_from_nonoverlapping(image_data.as_ptr(), image_data.len());
        device.unmap_memory(staging_buffer_memory);
    }

    let (texture_image, texture_image_memory) = image_view::create_image(
        &device,
        image_width,
        image_height,
        mip_levels,
        vk::SampleCountFlags::TYPE_1,
        vk::Format::R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
        vk::ImageTiling::OPTIMAL,
        vk::ImageUsageFlags::TRANSFER_SRC
            | vk::ImageUsageFlags::TRANSFER_DST
            | vk::ImageUsageFlags::SAMPLED,
        vk::MemoryPropertyFlags::DEVICE_LOCAL,
        device_memory_properties,
    );

    transiiton_image_layout(
        device, 
        command_pool, 
        submit_queue, 
        texture_image, 
        vk::Format::R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 
        vk::ImageLayout::UNDEFINED, 
        vk::ImageLayout::TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
        mip_levels,
    );

    copy_buffer_to_image(
        device,
        command_pool,
        submit_queue,
        staging_buffer,
        texture_image,
        image_width,
        image_height,
    );

    generate_mipmaps(
        device,
        command_pool,
        submit_queue,
        texture_image,
        image_width,
        image_height,
        mip_levels,
    );

    unsafe {
        device.destroy_buffer(staging_buffer, None);
        device.free_memory(staging_buffer_memory, None);
    }

    (texture_image, texture_image_memory, mip_levels)
}
```

Comment: My gamma sense is tingling, as incorrect configuration of gamma-to-linear or linear-to-gamma colour encoding can cause images to look washed out (I just can never remember which). I'd recommend examining where you import/create textures: do you have an option to interpret them as sRGB instead of linear? And then I'd examine where you set up your frame buffer / render operation: do you have an option to output sRGB to the screen instead of linear?

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah, this helps! I don't have time to look at my project at the moment, but in googling gamma correction in Vulkan I've got a waive of more trouble shooting possibilities.  Thanks!  I'll get back to you if I have definite answer.

Comment: Ok, The problem was that my image_view, and my texture were different formats.  Thanks!  You're comment helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special thanks to a comment by DMGregory!  The issue is caused because my Texture ImageView and my texture were using different formats. One was set to R8G8B8A_UNORM, and the other to R8G8B8A_SRGB.

Resolved by setting the format of both to R8G8B8A8_SRGB.